# How to check, is “X minutes” passed with timeStamp in C#?

Tags: c#, timespan

I am trying to create script that checks is the current time passed, but getting some errors.

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan pauseMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
TimeSpan compare = currentTime + pauseMin;
if (currentTime >= compare)
return null;
```

Comment: For wall time, use `System.DateTime`. For elapsed time, use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write this as

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan pauseMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
DateTime compare = currentTime.Add(pauseMin);
if (currentTime >= compare) {
    return null;
}
```

This uses the type of object that you are trying to represent with everything. DateTime's can have Timespan's added to them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Or Istern's answer if you are always just adding an integer of minutes to the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare DateTime and TimeSpan.

Try
`var compare = currentTime.AddMinutes(1)`

If you need to somehow use TimeSpan, use Jamie F's answer.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` and `TimeSpan` is different. You can use `currentTime` like this:

```
TimeSpan currentTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

And you can get passed minutes like this:

```
double minutes = (compare - currentTime).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: Tried to modify the code by your example, but still got the error.
TimeSpan currentTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DateTime.Now.Second);
TimeSpan pauseMin = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
TimeSpan compare = currentTime + pauseMin;
double minutes = (compare - currentTime).TotalMinutes;
if (currentTime >= minutes)
return null;

Comment: And you compare timespan with double. This is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pause for 1 minute, you can use

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);  // 1 minute = 60000 milliseconds
```

If you want your function to run for 1 minute, you can use something like

```
var returnAt = DateTime.Now().AddMinutes(1);

while ( true )
{ 
    // your code here ?

    if ( DateTime.Now() >= returnAt ) return null;
}
```